# how eliminate all columns whose have 0 values in one of their row?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna remove all columns whose have 0 in one of their rows:

```
Sk   col1       col2       col3
A      4         5           0
B       0        2           9
l       0        6           6
```

output:

```
Sk          col2       
A              5           
B              2           
l              6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boolean indexing with `eq(0)`+`any` and invert the match with `~`:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.eq(0).any()]
```

Alternatively with `ne` and `all`:

```
df.loc[:, df.ne(0).all()]
```

output:

```
  Sk  col2
0  A     5
1  B     2
2  l     6
```

Comment: can I count the number of  zeros in each column? in the above example is 2,0,1 for each column respectively

Comment: `df.eq(0).sum()`